# Move all Javascript to a separate file in Django

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

I'm beginning with Django and doing some stuff. I want to keep html files clean, without `<script>` blocks. Is it possible, even if my js part is using `{% url %}`  blocks?

Example:

`page.html`

```
<div> 
<h1> My home url is: </h1>
<div id="js-tag" ></div>
</div>
<script>
$(function(){
  $('#js-tag').html("{% url 'home' %}")
});
</script>
```

What I want to is remove this and place it on a separate js file and just import it to `page.html`

Comment: What do you mean by "without <script> blocks"? You have to bind your JavaScript files to your HTML files. I don't know how this could be done without <script src="yourjavascript.js"> direction.

Comment: I edited my question, sorry @cezar. Hope it's clear now...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(Almost) everything is possible with Django! ;)

You just have to put your JavaScript code in a separate HTML file and then you simply include it in your main template (here: `page.html`) like this:

```
{% include 'path/to/my/template_file/js_code.html' %}
```

Comment: You're right. There's no way to use template tags (e.g. `{% url '...' %}` in `.js` files.

Comment: But your suggestion is awesome, thank you very much!

Comment: @Leistungsabfall: Are you 100% sure that template tags can't be used in a .js file? I remember very good that I created .txt files in views and used template tags inside. I don't think that the template tags are possible only in .html files.

Comment: @cezar To use template tags in files they have to be served by Django. Maybe there are some ugly workarounds to force Django to also serve `.js` files instead of the usual static ones but imho this is by far more complex than the solution posted above.

Comment: @Leistungsabfall Yes, you're right. I thought about that after writing my comment. It's not a problem to generate a .js file with template tags by a django view. The problem arises after that in using that .js file.

Comment: This works but how to make an external .js file access the data coming from the Django backend?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use [django-js-reverse](https://github.com/ierror/django-js-reverse) to be able to used named URL patterns in js files.
You may also use the [staticfiles](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/) app to manage your static assets within Django.

That will allow you to include your js files this way:

```
{% load static %}  {# Only load static once at the top of your file #}
<script src="{% static 'path/to/js/in/staticfiles.js' %}"></script>
```

And in the js file you can use:

```
$('#js-tag').html(Urls.home());
```